# Excel of VSTO no to reflect?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

How to put excel vsto developed control, open while another excel this control can also have a click response. Or another way: Open a new excel, this control click will not reflect but before the excel workbook opens？

I try to know

```
  userControl = new UserControl();
                CustomTask = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(userControl, "nameofcontrol");

 UserControl userControl = (UserControl)CustomTask.Control;

            userControl.SwitchPanel_PivotBuilder(RefreshForm);

  public void SwitchPanel_PivotBuilder(bool RefreshForm = true)
        {
            if (formAnalyze == null)
            {
                formAnalyze = new FormAnalyze();
                formAnalyze.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                formAnalyze.TopLevel = false;
            }

            if (formAnalyze.InitForm_Analyze(RefreshForm))
            {
                panelMain.Controls.Clear();
                panelMain.Controls.Add(formAnalyze);
                formAnalyze.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                formAnalyze.SwitchTab(0);
                formAnalyze.Show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can't understand the question